# Will it be better for making call-for-action buttons in warm colors?

Tags: gui-design, user-research, visual-design

Are there any A/B test/ statistics results revealing whether using warm color buttons is generally better than cold color buttons in UI? (despite the concern for the theme color of the brand)

Comment: Reading the description this question sounds more appropriate for a search engine.

Comment: This is a visual design question, not really a UX one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on context (that means A/B testing*) :

**1) Color of the background and surrounding buttons**

You want the call to action button to out-stand so really it is more the text displayed, contrast, size and style than the colors that are going to make a difference.

As a rule you can consider that the bigger the button less brighter has to be its colour.

**2) Culture of the visitor**

Color is not going to be interpreted the same way by different people. Typically red is a color hard to use : it can be very outstanding but might be frighting.

To answer your question : no, it will not be better for making call-to-action buttons in warm colors because you certainly cannot make it a rule.

To illustrate there is my favorite home page :

[image]

**A/B testing cannot give a general answer, just inputs for a specific layout and content*